# регистрация и авторизация в Spring security websocket

Tags: java, websocket, spring-security, spring-boot

При реализации регистрации\авторизации в RESTfull можно найти много примеров, но если начать использовать websocket то эти подходы уже не помогут т.к. используются другие аннотации, входящие параметры при мапинге. Поиск в google на данную тему не выдает никаких конкретных примеров и вообще по spring websocket полно однотипных элементарных примеров типо эхо. Хочется увидеть реально работающий пример регистрации и авторизации с использованием spring security websocket.